# Domain user permissions on physical machines

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have:

- domain controller
- multiple domain users
- multiple windows workstations (client of this domain).

The windows workstation are physical fresh new computers. No configuration has been made on it, except joining the domain.

There is 3 points I do not understand:

- Is there a way to configure in active directory the local user permissions ? For example saying this domain user (or group) should be administrator on this physical computer. Or should I do that manually on each physical computer ?
- Is there a way to deny specific users on specific machines ? For example all users can connect on all workstations with RDP except one.
- I have tried to set local groups membership manually on one workstation. I do not understand but I can see my local groups memberships when I type `whoami /groups`, but I see a blank line "Local Group Memberships" in `net user bob /domain` command result. What is the reason ?
  Maybe `net user xxx /domain` is not designed to show local groups ? But in this case, why do I see a blank line "Local Group Memberships" ?
  I have tried to type `net user bob` (without /domain flag) but I get an error because this user does not exist locally.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to configure in active directory the local user permissions ? For example saying this domain user (or group) should be administrator on this physical computer. Or should I do that manually on each physical computer ?

Through Group Policy, use "Preferences > Control Panel > Local Users and Groups". (I think there was also a different way, but Preferences work well here and allow multiple overlapping GPOs to add their own admin groups.)

But if each computer has a specific user assigned as admin, it may be easier to just do it manually on each computer. (You can use `sc` to remotely start the WinRM service, then use `winrs` or PowerShell Remoting to remotely invoke `net localgroup /add`...)

You could of course use both – GPO to grant local admin to "IT staff" (and to remove "Domain Admins" from local admin!) but manually grant local admin to the assigned user.

> Is there a way to deny specific users on specific machines ? For example all users can connect on all workstations with RDP except one.

Through Group Policy, configure "Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > [Allow/Deny] log on through Remote Desktop Services". The default is already to allow only admins + members of "RDP Users".

This also be configured locally per-machine via gpedit.msc or secpol.msc, but as the default settings already disallow users that are not in "RDP Users", it's simpler to add/remove group members instead.

(Note: "Interactive" logon type includes both local and RDP logins, while "Network" logon type is for SMB access. If you install SSH, it's usually classified as "Interactive" but in some situations can be "Network".)

> I have tried to set local groups membership manually on one workstation. I do not understand but I can see my local groups memberships when I type whoami /groups, but I see a blank line "Local Group Memberships" in net user bob /domain command result. What is the reason ? Maybe net user xxx /domain is not designed to show local groups ? But in this case, why do I see a blank line "Local Group Memberships" ? I have tried to type net user bob (without /domain flag) but I get an error because this user does not exist locally.

It would show local memberships *on the domain controller,* apparently.

I suspect it's a relic of pre-AD domains (such as NetBIOS-based "NT domains"), as `net.exe` still has a lot of leftover code from that era – it even remembers OS/2 LAN Manager and even NetWare (such as the unused /fpnw switch).

Comment: Thanks but how can I see local group membership for a given user ?